# Secuencia numerica del ID autoincrementable

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, servidor

Alquien sabe como hacer para que cuando borre una fila de mi tabla MySQL, las siguientes sigan la secuencia numerica del ID autoincrementable? ejemplo, tengo 10 filas con ID  del 1 al 10, borro las filas 9 y 10, cuando ingreso 2 filas nuevas aparece asi: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12

Comment: ¿Y eso te causa algún problema específico? ¿O es solo que no te gusta ver que la secuencia quede con un hueco?

Comment: Practicamente si me causa un problema, porque mediante ajax traigo filas de la base de datos basados en el ID con la consulta:
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 ORDER BY 'ID' DESC LIMIT {$principio},10");

Comment: Tal vez puedes editar tu pregunta y explicar un poco más en cuanto al problema que te causa. Porque normalmente, es normal que la secuencia de ids no sea perfecta. Y el tratar de arreglar la secuencia para que quede perfecta, eso es lo que normalmente causa problemas.

Comment: Osea, si hago la consulta:     $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 ORDER BY 'ID' DESC LIMIT {$principio},10");    
nota que hay un   "" ORDER BY 'ID' "", no me causa problemas?

Comment: No veo que sea un problema. Pero si tu has notado que en realidad sea un problema, nuevamente, te animo a editar tu pregunta y explicarlo para que entendamos bien la razón de la pregunta.

Comment: El `Order by ID` funciona correctamente con los saltos, si te preocupa el LIMIT (que te va a retornar igualmente 10 filas, pero la ultima tendria de valor ID = 12 en vez de 10 "como antes") lo que debes hacer es filtrar en base al ID (Con `WHERE ID <= {$principio}). Por otro lado, debes entender que practicamente ningun sistema tiene problemas con ello, y que de lo contrario la practica mas sana es no borrar registros sinó tener un "Valor logico" de borrado (es decir, un atributo tipo BIT, o DATETIME, que contenga la informacion de que se borró) y filtrar por este en todo el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu dices no se puede hacer, a mi tampoco me gusta visualmente pero es asi como trabajan las BBDD solo puedes reiniciar el id si haces un truncate a la tabla es decir si la vacias. Si quieres ordenar los usuarios por orden de antiguedad te recomiendo añadir una columna fecha con la fecha en el momento de insertarlos y despues ordenar segun esa fecha.

Comment: **Es importante que leas [answer]** tu respuesta no provee una respuesta correcta para la pregunta.